# How to sort my array in my tableview by Date

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to return the following cells sorted by date. I have searched many posts but I can't really understand where I specifically put the sort by:

```
let sortedArray = jogs.sorted { $0.jogDate < $1.jogDate }
```

This is the function I use in my TableViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoCellIdentifier") as? ToDoCell else {
            fatalError("Could not dequeue a cell")
        }

        cell.delegate = self

        let jog = jogs[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel?.text = jog.title
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = jog.notes
        cell.dateLabel.text = Jog.jogDateFormatter.string(from: jog.jogDate)

        return cell
    }
```

Or should I put the sort in the Struct file? Also would a Class file be better than a Struct file?

Comment: is your data source always sorted by date? If so `jogs.sort { $0.jogDate < $1.jogDate }` in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Sort your jogs by date**

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()\
    jogs.sort { $0.jogDate < $1.jogDate }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

or

**2. Use your sorted array in UITableViewDelegate / Datasource implements**

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoCellIdentifier") as? ToDoCell else {
        fatalError("Could not dequeue a cell")
    }

    cell.delegate = self

    let jog = sortedArray[indexPath.row] // sorted array
    cell.titleLabel?.text = jog.title
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = jog.notes
    cell.dateLabel.text = Jog.jogDateFormatter.string(from: jog.jogDate)

    return cell
}
```

Comment:  Absolutely perfect thank you my friend! Implemented this and worked straight away. Big thank you!